# How to make the vector logo smaller and fit the icon

Tags: android, xml, vector

I have made a logo ic_launcher.xml for my android application using "New Vector Asset" and copying the vector paths from the asset into the ic_launcher_background.xml 
The logo that resulted is too big and cropped. In android I see only the central part, with sides, top and bottom cut off.
I would like for the vector to be smaller so it would be visible whole in the logo.

I have tried changing these values:

```
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
```

This resulted in the logo either being even bigger with more cropped out, or smaller, but not centered.

These are the paths for the vector:

```
    <path
        android:name="light_triangle"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M5,13.18v4L12,21l7,-3.82v-4L12,17l-7,-3.82zM12,3L1,9l11,6 9,-4.91V17h2V9L12,3z"/>
```

I would like for the logo to be smaller and centered. Can I somehow move the vector after making it smaller by changing height and width, or do I have to make new vector asset that is somehow smaller and centered?

UPDATE:
I have found what has to be done. I put the vectors inside a group like this:

```
    <group android:scaleY="0.7" android:scaleX="0.7" android:pivotY="10" android:pivotX="10">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M5,13.18v4L12,21l7,-3.82v-4L12,17l-7,-3.82zM12,3L1,9l11,6 9,-4.91V17h2V9L12,3z"/>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what has to be done. I put the vectors inside a group like this:

```
    <group android:scaleY="0.7" android:scaleX="0.7" android:pivotY="10" android:pivotX="10">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M5,13.18v4L12,21l7,-3.82v-4L12,17l-7,-3.82zM12,3L1,9l11,6 9,-4.91V17h2V9L12,3z"/>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vector image directly in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
 android:icon="@drawable/work_mode"
```

Comment: But I want to have a vector logo, not a png

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:width` and `android:height` values without changing the `android:viewportWidth` and `android:viewportHeight`. In this way :

```
android:width="16dp"
android:height="16dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
```